# Flask not launching with import modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, flask

My core Flask app code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from action_test import test1, test2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

However when i try to run it with python nothing really happens. The server is not launching and i receive no error. The process seems to start and thinks over and over in a loop.

If i comment out the line

```
#from action_test import test1, test2
```

the server starts normally. If i go into the python interpreter and execute the same line of code

```
from action_test import test1, test2
```

on itself it also works without any issues.

My action_test code is as follows:

```
import action2

def test1():
    fl = action2.FollowersList()
    mech = action2.Mechanics()
    manager = action2.Manager()
    manager.launch(mech,fl)
    for i in range(0,10):
        manager.iterate(mech,fl)

def test2():
    messageList = []
    fl = action2.FollowersList()
    mech = action2.Mechanics()
    manager = action2.Manager()
    manager.launch(mech,fl)
    for i in range(0,2000):
        message = manager.iterate(mech,fl)
        messageList.append(message)
    return messageList
```

This module also relies on import of another module, which is rich in classes and functions. When i am importing action_test on its own everything works just fine and the two functions test1 and test2 execute from the interpreter without a problem. The module action2 is totally flask independent and is designed to only execute some scripts that and do not define any @app.route kind of things or anything else related to Flask.

Why then Flask might have troubles with importing this module?

Comment: And what is in `action2`? What happens when you add `print` statements to various parts of the top-level of those modules?

Answer (score 1):

## Try running your app in debuger

Use either `pdb` or `ipdb`.

When I use `flaskr` sample application from Flask examples directory (be careful using the same version you have installed, master now contains broken changes), it looks like this:

### Start (i)pdb:

```
$ ((0.10.1)) ipdb flaskr.py 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/frontend.py:30: UserWarning: The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. All its subpackages have been moved to the top `IPython` level.
  warn("The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. "
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
> /home/javl/sandbox/flaskr/flask/examples/flaskr/flaskr.py(11)<module>()
     10     :license: BSD, see LICENSE for more details.
---> 11 """
     12
```

### Use `?` to see help for existing commands

```
ipdb> ?

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF    bt         cont      enable  jump  pdef    psource  run      unt   
a      c          continue  exit    l     pdoc    q        s        until 
alias  cl         d         h       list  pfile   quit     step     up    
args   clear      debug     help    n     pinfo   r        tbreak   w     
b      commands   disable   ignore  next  pinfo2  restart  u        whatis
break  condition  down      j       p     pp      return   unalias  where 

Miscellaneous help topics:
==========================
exec  pdb

Undocumented commands:
======================
retval  rv
```

### Use `n` for `next`

```
ipdb> n
> /home/javl/sandbox/flaskr/flask/examples/flaskr/flaskr.py(13)<module>()
     12 
---> 13 from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
     14 from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \

ipdb> n
> /home/javl/sandbox/flaskr/flask/examples/flaskr/flaskr.py(14)<module>()
     13 from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
---> 14 from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
     15      render_template, flash, _app_ctx_stack
```

### Use  to repeat last command

```
ipdb> 
> /home/javl/sandbox/flaskr/flask/examples/flaskr/flaskr.py(18)<module>()
     17 # configuration
---> 18 DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
     19 DEBUG = True
```

For me it breaks at the moment I go to line `app.run()`. But in your case you are fighting with some loop during application start, so if you get down to `app.run()`, you shall have your app debugged.

### What is name of your application script?

My guess is, you named that `action_test.py`. If this is the case, rename it to something what does not conflict with your packages and modules around.